# Book: Set Page Size

Tags: paper-size, books

Im fairly new in this forum, so please tell me if you need some more information or anything is unclear.

I'm planning on writing a book with LaTex and have found the Wiley Template here (http://www.latextemplates.com/template/wiley-book-style)

Is there any opportunity to set the layout to **DIN A4** ? I seems that the book is printed on letter format and then is cut. For me it would be easier if the `.pdf` is the size of the final book. So when I want my book to be 20x30cm the `.pdf` has the same size. Where can i set this?

I only found

```
\textheight=45pc 
\textwidth=28pc
```

in the `wileysev.cls` file.

Comment: `\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}`

Comment: Wiley decides about the layout and paper size. If you want to publish at their house, don't make changes. If you don't want to, why do you use that template?

Comment: @Johannes_B: Wiley publishes on Europe two,perhaps there's another template for A4 as well?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using the linked template (and cutting some stuff for convenience)

`\usepackage[a4paper,showframe]{geometry}` will work.

Perhaps the margins has to be set with `lmargin=...` etc (see the `geometry` package on this,please)

Remove the `showframe` option for production run.

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% Run LaTeX on this file several times to get Table of Contents,
%% cross-references, and citations.

%% If you have font problems, you may edit the w-bookps.sty file
%% to customize the font names to match those on your system.

%% w-bksamp.tex. Current Version: Feb 16, 2012
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
%  Sample file for
%  Wiley Book Style, Design No.: SD 001B, 7x10
%  Wiley Book Style, Design No.: SD 004B, 6x9
%
%
%  Prepared by Amy Hendrickson, TeXnology Inc.
%  http://www.texnology.com
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% 7x10
\documentclass{wileySev}

\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}

% 6x9
%\documentclass{wileySix}

\usepackage{graphicx}

%%%%%%%
%% for times math: However, this package disables bold math (!)
%% \mathbf{x} will still work, but you will not have bold math
%% in section heads or chapter titles. If you don't use math
%% in those environments, mathptmx might be a good choice.

% \usepackage{mathptmx}

% For PostScript text
\usepackage{w-bookps}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% Other packages you might want to use:

% for chapter bibliography made with BibTeX
% \usepackage{chapterbib}

% for multiple indices
% \usepackage{multind}

% for answers to problems
% \usepackage{answers}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% Change options here if you want:
%%
%% How many levels of section head would you like numbered?
%% 0= no section numbers, 1= section, 2= subsection, 3= subsubsection
%%==>>
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}

%% How many levels of section head would you like to appear in the
%% Table of Contents?
%% 0= chapter titles, 1= section titles, 2= subsection titles, 
%% 3= subsubsection titles.
%%==>>
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}

%% Cropmarks? good for final page makeup
%% \docropmarks

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
% DRAFT
%
% Uncomment to get double spacing between lines, current date and time
% printed at bottom of page.
% \draft
% (If you want to keep tables from becoming double spaced also uncomment
% this):
% \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.6}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%% Demo of section head containing sample macro:
%% To get a macro to expand correctly in a section head, with upper and
%% lower case math, put the definition and set the box 
%% before \begin{document}, so that when it appears in the 
%% table of contents it will also work:

\newcommand{\VT}[1]{\ensuremath{{V_{T#1}}}}

%% use a box to expand the macro before we put it into the section head:

\newbox\sectsavebox
\setbox\sectsavebox=\hbox{\boldmath\VT{xyz}}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% End Demo


\begin{document}


\booktitle{Survey Methodology}
\subtitle{This is the Subtitle}

\authors{Robert M. Groves\\
\affil{Universitat de les Illes Balears}
Floyd J. Fowler, Jr.\\
\affil{University of New Mexico}
}

\offprintinfo{Survey Methodology, Second Edition}{Robert M. Groves}

%% Can use \\ if title, and edition are too wide, ie,
%% \offprintinfo{Survey Methodology,\\ Second Edition}{Robert M. Groves}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% 
\halftitlepage

\titlepage


\begin{copyrightpage}{2007}
Survey Methodology / Robert M. Groves . . . [et al.].
\       p. cm.---(Wiley series in survey methodology)
\    ``Wiley-Interscience."
\    Includes bibliographical references and index.
\    ISBN 0-471-48348-6 (pbk.)
\    1. Surveys---Methodology.  2. Social 
\  sciences---Research---Statistical methods.  I. Groves, Robert M.  II. %
Series.\\

HA31.2.S873 2007
001.4'33---dc22                                             2004044064
\end{copyrightpage}



\dedication{To my parents}

\begin{contributors}
\name{Masayki Abe,} Fujitsu Laboratories Ltd., Fujitsu Limited, Atsugi,
Japan

\name{L. A. Akers,} Center for Solid State Electronics Research, Arizona
State University, Tempe, Arizona

\name{G. H. Bernstein,} Department of Electrical and
Computer Engineering, University of Notre Dame, Notre Dame, South Bend, 
Indiana; formerly of
Center for Solid State Electronics Research, Arizona
State University, Tempe, Arizona 
\end{contributors}

\contentsinbrief
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables


\begin{foreword}
This is the foreword to the book.
\end{foreword}

\begin{preface}
This is an example preface.
This is an example preface.
This is an example preface.
This is an example preface.

\prefaceauthor{R. K. Watts}
\where{Durham, North Carolina\\
September, 2007}

\end{preface}


\begin{acknowledgments}
From Dr.~Jay Young, consultant from Silver Spring, Maryland, I received
the initial push to even consider writing this book. Jay was a constant
``peer reader'' and very welcome advisor durying this year-long process.


To all these wonderful people I owe a deep sense of gratitude especially now
that this project has been completed.
\authorinitials{G. T. S.}
\end{acknowledgments}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{}
```

will work